# How to input text from textbox in arraylist

Tags: c#, parsing, arraylist, combobox, textbox

I have to do a form in C#. In my form I have placed some textboxes: idBox, descBox, priceBox and qtdBox. What I have been trying to do is get the text from the textboxes and parse it into different types like decimal and int because these are the types needed in my Product class as parameters from constructor. From here i add them in an arraylist of Product objects. Then I would like to display the ToString of Product as individual item in a ComboBox that has the same name. But when I do only the string Product field displays normally and others display 0. What is wrong there?

Product Class

```
    class Product
    {
    private int id;
    private String description;
    private decimal price;
    private int quantity;

    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return id;
        }
        set
        {
            if( id > 0)
            {
                id = value;
            }  
        }
    }
    public String Description
    {
        get
        {
            return description;
        }
        set
        {
            description = value;
        }
    }
    public decimal Price
    {
        get
        {
            return price;
        }
        set
        {
            if (price > 0)
            {
                price = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public int Quantity
    {
        get
        {
            return quantity;
        }
        set
        {
            if (quantity > 0)
            {
                quantity = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public Product(int formID, String formDescription, decimal formPrice, int formQuantity)
    {
        this.ID = formID;
        this.Description = formDescription;
        this.Price = formPrice;
        this.Quantity = formQuantity;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"ID: {this.ID}, Description: {this.Description}, Price: {this.Price}, Quantity: {this.Quantity} \n"; 
    }
}
```

Form Class

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    ArrayList productList = new ArrayList();

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String text = null;
        text += "All Products \n";
        foreach(Product p in productList)
        {
            text += p.ToString();
        }
        MessageBox.Show(Text);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(idBox.Text!=null && descBox.Text != null && priceBox.Text != null && qtdBox.Text != null)
        {
            String text1 = idBox.Text;
            int number = int.Parse(text1);
            decimal price;
            decimal.TryParse(priceBox.Text, out price);
            String text2 = qtdBox.Text;
            int quantity = int.Parse(text2);
            String normal = descBox.Text;
            String error = null;
            try
            {
                int num = Convert.ToInt32(idBox.Text);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                error += "The product has an incorrect ID format \n";
            }

            try
            {
                decimal pr = Decimal.Parse(priceBox.Text);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                error += "The product has an incorrect price format \n";
            }

            try
            {
                int qt = Convert.ToInt32(qtdBox.Text);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                error += "The product has an incorrect quantity format \n";
            }

            if(error == null)
            {
                Product p = new Product(number, normal, price, quantity);
                productList.Add(p);
                label6.Text = p.ToString();
                comboBox.Items.Add(p.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show("Product Added Successfully");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"{error}");
            }
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (idBox.Text != "" && descBox.Text != "" && priceBox.Text != "" && qtdBox.Text != "")
        {
            int number = Convert.ToInt32(idBox.Text);
            decimal price = Decimal.Parse(priceBox.Text);
            int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(qtdBox.Text);
            String error = null;

            try
            {
                int num = Convert.ToInt32(idBox.Text);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                error += "The product has an incorrect ID format \n";
            }

            try
            {
                decimal pr = Decimal.Parse(priceBox.Text);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                error += "The product has an incorrect price format \n";
            }

            try
            {
                int qt = Convert.ToInt32(qtdBox.Text);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                error += "The product has an incorrect quantity format \n";
            }

            if (error == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Product Removed Successfully");
                Product p1 = new Product(number, descBox.Text, price, quantity);
                foreach(Product p in productList)
                {
                    if (p.ID.Equals(p1.ID))
                    {
                        productList.Remove(p);
                    }
                }
                comboBox.Items.Remove(p1.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"{error}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any Help is appreciated

Comment: In your properties you have restrictions such as `if (price > 0) price = value`. This stops the property from ever being assigned - the variable `price` starts with a default value of zero, so it'll never meet the condition to assign the property to something else. Probably, you meant `if (value > 0) price = value`.

Comment: Ohhhh my bad. Thanks @steve16351

Comment: change this too

    "foreach (Product p in productList)
                    {
                        if (p.ID.Equals(p1.ID))
                        {
                            productList.Remove(p);
                        }
                    }"
you can't remove element from iterating collection,there will be error

Comment: ArrayList is deprecated. Use List<T> instead!!